# Detecting SetCursorPos()?

Tags: winapi, mouse

You can probably figure out why I am asking this question. Even if not, it's very simple.
My question is whether it is possible to detect the use of SetCursorPos() on one's own application, without scanning other running applications for any calls to this API.

For example, if I have my cursor in a window and I call SetCursorPos(), can this window in anyway know that the cursor placement is not directly from the mouse (raw input)?

I am not oblivious to the fact that you can 'know' whether a mouse input is raw simply by checking how the position alters; for example, if the position changes from 100(X) & 100(Y) to 500(X) and 500(Y), without moving through each individual location between these two, then with certainty, something has altered the mouse position.

If anyone of you know of a way to produce 'raw mouse input', without any application being able to tell the difference between the output from a function, and that from a mouse--if there is such a difference--then that'd suffice, too.

Of course, whenever I move my mouse, the operating system I am using detects this and then appropriately moves the cursor accordingly. In practice, I should be able to alter this low level functionality as to my will?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way for a window to directly determine how the mouse was moved.  External applications could be using `SetCursorPos()`, but they could also be using lower level functions like `mouse_event()` or `SendInput()` instead.  By the time the notification reach the target window, the OS has already normalized the data and any source information is lost  If you really needed to detect use of `SetCursorPos()` or other functions, you would have to directly hook into those functions in every running process.  Alternatively, you might try registering for "Raw Input" via `RegisterRawInputDevices()` and see if you get a corresponding notification from the mouse hardware directy, assumine those simulating functions do not trigger Raw notifications as well.

Comment: Thanks! Everything I needed to know. The reason I am asking, given that you don't see it, as I can tell, is to avoid a potential ban. That's all.. I was figuring that most anti-cheat modules for FPS shooters would.. somehow... detect the use of this function; however, these programs are not allowed to scan outside of their own space, so there's no chance of getting caught by them actually scanning my program for the use of this function.